# can view source be disabled by a website?

Tags: language-agnostic

Is it possible I create a webpage that doesn't allow the website source to be displayed?

Comment: No. You're asking to break functionality in a web browser. The only difference between how your site looks in the browser and the source is how the browser renders it.

Comment: It's actually quite easy: Password-protect it (`.htaccess`) and give nobody the credentials. It's a problem similar to that of the movie and software industry. They need to give you their goods for viewing/regular use, but want to prevent further access. Like giving someone a key to a door and wanting them not entering the room behind. It just doesn't work.

Comment: @DanielBeck _The Only Secure Computer Is One That's Unplugged, Locked In A Safe, And Buried 20 Feet Under The Ground In A Secret Location._

Comment: @likeitlikeit The question states *doesn't allow*, not *makes it impossible*. Also, this was over two years ago. Really?

Comment: @DanielBeck thanks, didn't notice that. I liked your comment though. The basic issue is a timeless one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot hide the plain text HTML output of your web server.

How the HTML is generated is separate form the actual HTML that gets sent from the server.

This is the way the internet and world wide web were designed. If you are using a server-side scripted web application to generate your HTML, then your business intelligence / process / code is hidden, provided that people do not have access to browse the actual script file on your server.

If you would like to customize one of the open source browsers, like Firefox or Chrome, you could disable the "view source" functionality. It might be a worthwhile option for certain intranet or internal business applications. XUL and Firefox is one of the possibilities our company looked at to control what the end user could access. The only real security you have to keep your source secure is on the server side, as network / protocol monitors could still pull the HTML as it moves over the network.

Answer (score 12):

**No.**

Comment: Could you please drop a line concerning the reason for this?

Comment: @Mehper C. Palavuzlar: A reason shouldn't be needed. Anything that can open a file through the HTTP protocol can obviously view the source of said file. Heck, **notepad can open a URL** and it certainly doesn't care what the contents of the html file are.

Answer (score 5):

From [encrypt-html.com](http://www.encrypt-html.com/_disable_view_source.htm):

> Almost all browsers provide a
>   convenient way to view the source code
>   of the currently opened page. We
>   regularly receive e-mails with the
>   same question - how to disable view
>   source command.
>
> An html file can not enable or disable
>   the built in browser functionality in
>   most cases. It's not possible remove
>   the view-source command from the
>   browser menus or to make it
>   non-working. But if the source is
>   encrypted, what the user will see is
>   just a lot of garbage characters - not
>   your original code. So the view source
>   command is practically disabled for
>   each encrypted file.

Comment: Encrypting HTML do not protect against DOM viewers (for example Google Chrome natively shows parsed DOM tree, by right-clicking and selecting "Inspect element").

Comment: Encrypting the "source" does nothing other than prevent a casual person from viewing source as everything necessary for decrypting said file has to be available in a javascript function in the source itself.

Answer (score 1):

You might use plugin based content, like a java applet, Flash, etc., to somewhat "hide" the real content. Of course, as eventually it will be displayed on screen, there is nothing to prevent a determined user to reverse engineer your page.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a site with "view source code" disabled in any browser: http://www.transelectrica.ro/StareSistem/protocoale/starea_sistemului.php The question is: HOW THEY DID IT?

Comment: That's not really an answer, but still an interesting thing. Apparently, they use an image. However, of course, both Firebug and Chrome Inspector still show the HTML. However, the `show source` links are actually greyed out.

Comment: This page, although it is served by a PHP file, actually only transmits a PNG image. Thus, there is no source code to display

Answer (score 0):

i have use block methode disable right click but still can view source on chrome using metode tipe to address bar `view-source:example.com`

disable right click

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function disableSelection(target){
if (typeof target.onselectstart!="undefined") //IE route
target.onselectstart=function(){return false}
else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect!="undefined") //Firefox route
target.style.MozUserSelect="none"
else //All other route (ie: Opera)
target.onmousedown=function(){return false}
target.style.cursor = "default"
}
</script>
<body oncontextmenu='return false;'>
<script type='text/javascript'>
disableSelection(document.body);
```