# How to disable users not to view pagesource on a website?

Tags: html

Disable all the possiblities of users viewing the page source by differnt keys like(ctrl+u,rightclick )

Comment: If the user is rendering your page in their browser, they necessarily have received the page source.  So trying to prevent them from viewing it is a moot point.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967319/can-view-source-be-disabled-by-a-website

Comment: I'd suggest that you don't worry about it. If what you have on your page is so important that others shouldn't be able to see it, don't put it on a webpage.  Remember one thing. We can view this source using firebug or some other third party tools. So we cant do this 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't do this.  There is no way to secure the page source since it is required by the client to view your site. Blocking different keys will just lead to bad user experiences. If you want to make it harder to read you can minify your html/js/css but honestly there is nothing so interesting in your page source that you would need to protect it.

If you do have something you need to protect (such as private keys, passwords, etc) then you need to get these out of the page source since there is no way to protect them properly.  These things should be kept on the server instead.

Answer (score -2):

Cover the webpage with an Animated screen